# Why then is $df(x)$ surjective if and only if $Ax\neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

$\forall x\in \mathbb R^k$, define the linear map $df(x):\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R$ as follows:$\forall \xi\in \mathbb R^k, df(x)(\xi)=2x^TA\xi$, where $A$ is symmetric. Why then  is $df(x)$ surjective if and only if $Ax\neq 0$?

Here is what I tried:

For $\forall a\in \mathbb R^k,b\in\mathbb R$, the equation $2x^TAa=b$ should have at least one solution, therefore $2x^TA$ should be invertible, but hey, it's not a square matrix, how can we find a inverse for a non square matrix? Please help:),

Comment: *should have at least one solution, therefore $2x^TA$ should be invertible* There is quite a bit wrong with this. In order to talk about invertibility, the domain and codomain need to have the same dimension. And even then, you can have solutions without it being invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of an $\Bbb R$-linear map into $\Bbb R$ is a subspace, so it is either $\{0\}$ or all of $\Bbb R$. That's why it suffices to prove that it's just nonzero.